# Show that there exists a $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

Tags: calculus

No idea where to start on this question. Any help is appreciated:

> $$\text{Show that there exists a $x \in \mathbb{R}$  such that } x^{21}+\frac{200}{1+x^4+\cos^2x}=120$$

Thank you

Comment: Why `polynomials`?

Comment: There is even an $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Hint: intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Check out [our guide for askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) and try to improve the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

Define $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(x) = x^{21}+\frac{200}{1+x^4+\cos^2x}$.

Clearly $f$ is continuous and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) = \pm\infty$.

Hence $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$f(0)=100<120$$ and the fraction is always positive. Hence we are sure that

$$f(2)>2^{21}>120.$$

As the function is continuous, it must cross $120$.